# What makes my SQL Update script act different on different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm migrating a database from one server to another. When validating some reports, I'm finding differences that are due to the following update script:

```
UPDATE
    #t
SET
    OtherValueID = t4.OtherValueID 
FROM
    #t t
    INNER JOIN #t4 t4 ON t.ValueID = t4.ValueID 
WHERE
    t.OtherValueID IS NULL
```

So, on Server 1, this script sets OtherValueID to 123 for ValueID 1. On server 2, this script sets OtherValueID to 456 for ValueID 1.

I understand that the issue is that #t4 contains duplicate OtherValueID's for ValueID = 1, and this script should be changed. However, what I would like to know is what is different about the 2 servers that would make the Update perform differently? I would understand if it was just "random", but that's not the case since Server 1 returns the same value every time and same with Server 2.

The server versions are the same. I did a redgate SQL compare to confirm the schema is the exact same on both servers. Is there anything else that would factor in to this, or are the possibilities so limitless or impossible to access that I should just stop trying?

Comment: It has to be differences in the data not the schema. The join must be matching on different rows or the rows have different values in OtherValueID.

Comment: Ohh and since you say you have duplicates...it is definitely possible that you would get different results because of that. What happens is the engine will use the "last" value in the list of duplicates. Since you have nothing to control which one of multiple the join will match on it is entirely possible the new server returns in a different order.

Comment: You need further criteria to determine - predictably - which matching row will be used. Otherwise, SQL Server's choice is arbitrary / non-deterministic. Forget about two different servers, you could get different answers on the same server.

Comment: For reference, I performed these steps in a separate query window. First, #t and #t4 on both servers contain the exact same data in the same order. Second (@Aaron), I can run the script on each server any number of times and get the exact same result. That result just happens to be different between the 2 servers.

Comment: A table is, by definition, an unordered bag of rows. It isn't "contained ... in the same order." Also, I said you *could* get different results on the same server. Maybe not today, but maybe next week, or next month, or after a service pack, or after a restart of SQL Server, etc. etc. Again: ***A TABLE IS AN UNORDERED SET OF ROWS.*** If you always want a certain row to be updated, identify ***THAT ROW*** in an unambiguous way. Please take a look at [assumption #3 here](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/).